# react router server rendering pass url params to load data dispatch function mentioned in documentation

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

I'm using server-side rendering with `redux` and `react-router-dom` v4.

As mentioned in [documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/server-rendering.md) the server side needs some initial dispatch some actions to preload the data from the server.

So I used the same function for the server and its working when the dispatch function does not have any parameter pass to it. But in case I need to pass some params from URL to dispatch function then how will I use that param from route to dispatch my action.

My case is

```
routes = [{
    path: "/article/:url",
    exact: true,
    render: RenderArticleDetailPage,
    loadData: getStoryDetailFromApi(url),
},
 ...other_routes,
]
```

The url passes to `getStoryDetailFromApi()` is same as url param to path of a route.

The action function is

```
export const getStoryDetailFromApi =  (url = null) => dispatch => {
    return axios({
        url: baseURL + "article/" + url,
        headers: headers,
    }).then((response) => {
        dispatch(getStory(response.data))
    }).catch((error) => {
        //logger.log(error);
    });
};
```

So, how could I get that url param from loadData function ?

Comment: The `loadData` function is arbitrarily named `loadData`. The documentation you notes gives an example of using `matchPath` to load the data at the correct time. You will need to load your data and then do something with your data. For example you can render the data to a variable on `window` so when the page loads that data is available to your app. See http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html

Comment: Even I am searching for a solution to the same problem. By any chance, were you able to figure out how to read URL parameters in loadData function?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/server-rendering.md I apply this approach to get initial data on server side.